Dimension of Cartesian Product of Posets
A poset is a pair $P = (X, \leq)$ where $X$ is a finite set and $\leq$ is a binary relation that is reflexive, transitive, and antisymmetric.
Let now $ P = (X_P, \leq_P) $ and $ Q = (X_Q, \leq_Q) $ be posets. Define the poset $ R $ as $ (X_P \times X_Q, \leq) $, where:
$
X_P \times X_Q = \{(x, y) \mid x \in X_P, y \in X_Q\},
$
and the order $ \leq $ on $ R $ is defined as:
$
(x, y) \leq (x', y') \quad \text{if and only if} \quad x \leq_P x' \text{ and } y \leq_Q y',
$
for $ x, x' \in X_P $ and $ y, y' \in X_Q $.
I read in many textbooks that the following upper bound is rather easy to see
$
\dim(R) \leq \dim(P) + \dim(Q).
$
where the dimension of a poset $P$, denoted as $dim(P)$, is the smallest number of total orders the intersection of which gives rise to the partial order.
However, I fail to see reason for this rather obvious fact. What is the construction of these total orders here?

Let $m=\dim P$ and $n=\dim Q$.
Let $(\preceq_1,\dots,\preceq_m)$ be a list of total orders on $P$ whose intersection is $\le_P$.
Let $(\unlhd_1,\dots,\unlhd_n)$ be a list of total orders on $Q$ whose intersection is $\le_Q$.
For each $i\in \{1,\dots,m\}$, define a total order $\preceq_i'$ on $P\times Q$ as follows.
$$
(p_1,q_1)\preceq'_i(p_2,q_2) \iff p_1\preceq_i p_2 \text{ or } (p_1=p_2\text{ and }q_1\unlhd_1 q_2)
$$
For each $j\in \{1,\dots,n\}$, define a total order $\unlhd_j
'$ on $P\times Q$ as follows.
$$
(p_1,q_1)\unlhd'_j(p_2,q_2) \iff q_1\unlhd_j q_2 \text{ or } (q_1=q_2\text{ and }p_1\preceq_1 p_2)
$$
I claim that $(\preceq_1',\dots,\preceq_m', \unlhd_1',\dots,\unlhd_n')$ is a list of $m+n$ total orders on $P\times Q$ whose intersection is $\le$. This proves that $\dim R\le m+n=\dim P+\dim Q$.
It is easy to see that $\preceq_i'$ and $\unlhd_j'$ are valid linear extensions of $P\times Q$, for each $i\in \{1,\dots,m\}$ and each $j\in \{1,\dots,n\}$. Conversely, we must show that if $(p_1,q_1)\preceq_i'(p_2,q_2)$ for all $i$ and $(p_1,q_1)\unlhd_j'(p_2,q_2)$ for all $j$, then $(p_1,q_1)\le (p_2,q_2)$.
Since $(p_1,q_1)\preceq_i'(p_2,q_2)$ for all $i$, we have for each $i$ that $p_1\preceq_i p_2$ or $p_1=p_2$, so in either case $p_1\preceq_i p_2$. Since $p_1\preceq_i p_2$ for all $i$, and since the intersection of $(\preceq_1,\dots,\preceq_m)$ equals $\le_P$, we get $p_1\le_P p_2$. Similarly, we get $q_1\le_Q q_2$. Combined, this proves $(p_1,q_1)\le (p_2,q_2)$, as claimed.
